# call jquery function onload

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery function that show a information box when I click a button, this works fine but I would like to be able to show the same information box when the page has loaded (without the need to press a button). But it does not work, what am I doing wrong?

```
    // notification
if(jQuery('#growl2').length > 0) {
    jQuery('#growl2').click(function(){
        var msg = "Tip: Copy partnumber by searching for an exsisting and select it from grid.";
        jQuery.jGrowl(msg, { life: 5000});
    });
}
```

And this is placed just before the end of body...

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var msg = "Tip: Copy partnumber by searching for an exsisting and select it from grid.";
     jQuery.jGrowl(msg, { life: 5000 });
 });
```

It only works when I click this button..

```
<a id="growl2" class="btn btn-default"><small>Show message</small></a>
```

Comment: Try changing `$(document).ready()` to `jQuery(document).ready()` or search for jQuery `noConflict()`. Your code looks ok, looks like the problem is outside the blocks you have provided.

Comment: Maybe it's a magical button? Why not just do `jQuery('#growl2').trigger('click')`

Comment: put that block + the jquery link in the head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works when you move it from before `body` to before `head`.

This issue may also occur if defer the loading of jQuery by placing jQuery.js` before body tag.

So either move the code before head tag or move `<script src="jQuery.js" ></script>` before head tag

or you use this instead

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    var msg = "Tip: Copy partnumber by searching for an exsisting and select it from grid.";
     jQuery.jGrowl(msg, { life: 5000 });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following:

```
function loadjGrowl() {
   var msg = "Tip: Copy partnumber by searching for an exsisting and select it from grid.";
   jQuery.jGrowl(msg, { life: 5000 });
}

window.onload = loadjGrowl;
```

**Note:** This fires when the page is fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

if your button click handler works fine, you can just activate it right after attaching it by calling `.click()` without a function argument:

```
if(jQuery('#growl2').length > 0) {
    jQuery('#growl2').click(function(){
        var msg = "Tip: Copy partnumber by searching for an exsisting and select it from grid.";
        jQuery.jGrowl(msg, { life: 5000});
    }).click();   //  <---- this
}
```